# Check if a string contains a character in a unicode range (using Ruby)

Tags: ruby, unicode

I want to create a simple function in Ruby that will check if the given string contains any unicode characters in the ranges such as the following:

- U+007B -- U+00BF
- U+02B0 -- U+037F
- U+2000 -- U+2BFF

How can I accomplish this? Google is coming up blank for me, all things about removing unicode characters or checking if a string contains unicode.

Comment: unicode strings are of the form `"\u007B"` in ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing would probably be a regex using [`String#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-index), [`String#match`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-match), or even [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
string.index(/[\u007B-\u00BF\u02B0-\u037F\u2000-\u2BFF]/)
string.match(/[\u007B-\u00BF\u02B0-\u037F\u2000-\u2BFF]/)
string[/[\u007B-\u00BF\u02B0-\u037F\u2000-\u2BFF]/]
```

All three will give you `nil` (which is falsey) if they don't find the pattern and non-`nil` (which will be truthy) if they do.

Comment: You might also be interested in the Unicode character property support (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) depending on what you're trying to do, that lets you use things like `\p{Cyrillic}` instead of manual ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I would do as below:

```
my_string = "{ How are you ?}"                                     
puts my_string.chars.any? { |chr| ("\u007B".."\u00BF").include?(chr) }  
#=> true
```

Comment: But this will only check one character at a time so you'd have to split the incoming string into characters and test each one against the range or use the set-ish operators on arrays of characters I suppose.

Comment: @muistooshort I made a guess on the behalf of the OP, as his question is not clear enough, and decided to give a clue to get him started

Comment: The differentiation between "string" and "character" is in the question: "... given string contains any unicode characters ..."